# Compare time value in a text field to current time

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

In PostgreSQL I have a text column that contains values representing start and stop times of events in this format: "15:00-17:00" (e.g. that's an event that starts at 3pm and ends at 5pm). I need to write an SQL query that returns rows where the event has not yet ended. For example, if I query at 16:48, the event above would be returned because it is not yet 17:00. If it helps, I'm only concerned with the hour value, minutes can be ignored.

If the data were in proper time fields, this would be trivial but I'm little baffled as to how to do it when the data is text. I assume I can use some kind of regex to parse out just the 2nd hour value and maybe combine that with CURRENT_TIME for some kind of comparison but I'm not really sure how to put it all together.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Working with substring at the moment, trying to get something like this to work: SUBSTRING("startstoptimes" FROM 7 FOR 2) >= DATE_PART('hour', now())

Comment: @steevithak ... which is why it's best to mention your Pg version in questions. Also, please note that there isn't really a meaningful '8.x' - for example the difference between the unsupported 8.2 and the supported 8.4 is *huge*, with 8.4 adding CTEs, window functions, unnest(), and more. Please specify the full version or at least (x.y) version, otherwise it's like saying "Windows 6.x" - do you mean 6.0 Vista, or 6.1 Windows 7? There's a big difference!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a text compare with the pseudodate field. You can even check minutes, since they're still in lexicographic order.

```
... WHERE SUBSTR(datefield, 7, 5) >= to_char(NOW(), 'HH24:MI');
```

or maybe

```
... WHERE split_part(datefield, '-', 2) >= to_char(NOW(), 'HH24:MI');
```

You can also check with regexp, just in case you get "17:00 to 23:00" or something:

```
... WHERE substring(datefield from '\d\d:\d\d$') >= to_char(NOW(), 'HH24:MI')
    AND   substring(datefield from '^\d\d:\d\d') <= to_char(NOW(), 'HH24:MI');
```

This last check should automatically ignore badly formatted dates.

Comment: Thanks, Erwin's answer is good too but I'm using PostgreSQL 8.x so I'll stick with this solution for now.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  now()::time BETWEEN left(time_col, 5)::time
                   AND    right(time_col, 5)::time
```

This returns all rows from table `tbl` where the *current local time* `now()::time` lies between begin and end encoded in the column `time_col` - meaning they have started, but not ended yet. This obviously requires well-formed strings in `time_col` that match the pattern in your question exactly.

[`left()` and `right()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html) have been introduced with PostgreSQL 9.1. In older versions you can substitute with `substr()` expressions like @lserni already provided.